# Woocommerce : Could not find asset registry

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue with my WooCommerce page. I tried to deactivate all plugins except WooCommerce on my Wordpress website. Could you please help me with this issue? (I tried to search everywhere for the solution but without success :/ )
I don't really want to reinstall Woocommerce if possible.

Any ideas would help, thank you very much :)

*Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Could not find asset registry for wp-admin-scripts in /data/web/virtuals/298612/virtual/www/domains/miltexshop.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/Internal/Admin/WCAdminAssets.php:128 Stack trace: #0 /data/web/virtuals/298612/virtual/www/domains/miltexshop.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/Internal/Admin/WCAdminAssets.php(401): Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\Admin\WCAdminAssets::get_script_asset_filename('wp-admin-script...', 'product-trackin...') #1 /data/web/virtuals/298612/virtual/www/domains/miltexshop.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/tracks/events/class-wc-products-tracking.php(355): Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\Admin\WCAdminAssets::register_script('wp-admin-script...', 'product-trackin...', false) #2 /data/web/virtuals/298612/virtual/www/domains/miltexshop.cz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): WC_Products_Tracking->possibly_add_product_tracking_scripts('edit.php') #3 /data/web/virtuals/298612/virtual/www/domains/miltexshop.cz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): W in /data/web/virtuals/298612/virtual/www/domains/miltexshop.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/Internal/Admin/WCAdminAssets.php on line 128*

[image: Network]

WCAdminAssets.php (function : get_script_asset_filename)

```
/**
 * Gets a script asset registry filename. The asset registry lists dependencies for the given script.
 *
 * @param  string $script_path_name Path to where the script asset registry is contained.
 * @param  string $file File name (without extension).
 * @return string complete asset filename.
 *
 * @throws \Exception Throws an exception when a readable asset registry file cannot be found.
 */
public static function get_script_asset_filename( $script_path_name, $file ) {
    $minification_supported = Features::exists( 'minified-js' );
    $script_min_filename    = $file . '.min.asset.php';
    $script_nonmin_filename = $file . '.asset.php';
    $script_asset_path      = WC_ADMIN_ABSPATH . WC_ADMIN_DIST_JS_FOLDER . $script_path_name . '/';

    // Check minification is supported first, to avoid multiple is_readable checks when minification is
    // not supported.
    if ( $minification_supported && is_readable( $script_asset_path . $script_min_filename ) ) {
        return $script_min_filename;
    } elseif ( is_readable( $script_asset_path . $script_nonmin_filename ) ) {
        return $script_nonmin_filename;
    } else {
        // could not find an asset file, throw an error.
        throw new \Exception( 'Could not find asset registry for ' . $script_path_name );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a build tool failure to compile something.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely overwrite the woocommerce plugin.
Sometimes during plugin updates (especially if you keep changing things in the backend) the update fails even though wp show it's sucessfull.

If this occurs 99/100 it's because woocommerce is missing files.
If you don't want to remove it, [download it from wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) or [github (with the label `latest`)](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/releases)  and overwrite it with ssh or (s)ftp.